# $\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{5-x^2}}dx$ using substitution $u = \sqrt{5-x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I was trying to solve $$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{5-4x^2 }} dx$$ by using the substitution
$$
u=\sqrt{5-4x^2}\\
dx = \frac{\sqrt{5-4x^2}}{-4x}du$$ So the integral can be written as $$\int \left(-\frac{x}{4}\right) du$$ and
$$
x= \begin{cases}
\sqrt{(5-u^2)/4}, & x >0\\
-\sqrt{(5-u^2)/4}, &x<0
\end{cases}
$$
I've rewritten the integral as
$$-\frac18\int\sqrt{5-u^2}du$$
using trig substitution with $$u= \sqrt5\sin(t)$$ we have
$$-\frac5{16}t - \frac5{16} \sin(t)\cos(t)$$ $$t=\arcsin\left(\frac{u^2}{\sqrt5}\right)$$
If we now reverse the substitutions and simplify, I got the final answer as $$-\frac5{16} \arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{5-4x^2}5}\right) - \frac{x}8\sqrt{5-4x^2} $$However this differs from the answer in my textbook which is:

$$-\frac{x}{8}\sqrt{5-4x^2}+\frac5{16}\arcsin\left(\frac{2x}{\sqrt5}\right)+C$$

My textbook used different methods that are simpler and easier, but I want to know where I made a mistake.

Comment: Keep in mind that anti-derivatives are only defined up to an additive constant.  Have you checked to see whether your solution differs from the official solution by an additive constant?  Also...you could try to check your result by differentiating it.

Comment: Also:  I think you would get a better response here if you tried to format your post properly.  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting.

Comment: Lulu yes my solution differs by more than a constant in the textbook there is a term $$arcsin(2x/sqrt(5) )$$ in my result the corresponding term is $$arcsign(sqrt(5-x^2)/sqrt(5) ))$$

Comment: Lulu i read that tutorial this is my second attempt to reformat the question.

Comment: Typing `$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{5-x^2}}$` produces $\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{5-x^2}}$ .

Comment: Well...things like sqrt need to be preceded by a slash.  thus "\sqrt {5-x^2}" formats as $\sqrt {5-x^2}$.

Comment: To your computation, I note that in the penultimate step you had a $u^2$ which should have come to $(5-x^2)$ in the end, not the square root of that.

Comment: lulu that is a mistake $$t=arcsin(u/\sqrt(5))$$ now i can not edit the question so however edited it please pay attention.

Comment: Note that $\sin^{-1}(\sqrt {1-x^2}) +\sin^{-1}(x)$ is a constant for $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: lulu that is interesting could you explain moe how that makes the two terms in my solution and the text book equal? Do not forget that in my solution we have a factor of 1/sqrt(5) multiplied by the sqrt and in the textbook it is multiplied by the same factor also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{5-4x^2}5}= \arccos\sqrt{1-\frac{5-4x^2}5}
=\arccos\frac{2x}{\sqrt5}=\frac\pi2-\arcsin\frac{2x}{\sqrt5}
$$
Therefore, the two results differs by the constant $-\frac\pi2$.

Comment: Thank you very much this is sooo helpful and thanks to lulu and everyone who helped you guys are much better the ones who replied to me the last time i posted the same question they were rude and instead ofhelping they just closed it.

Comment: So basically my solution is correct?

Comment: @Hfdssdjns - your result is correct, though the approach could be improved

Comment: Thank you. Actually my textbook has a much simpler approach i just was curious about this substitution

Answer (score 1):

**Integration by parts**
$$
\begin{aligned}
I&=\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{5-x^2}} d x \\
& =-\int x d\left(\sqrt{5-x^2}\right) \\
& =-x \sqrt{5-x^2}+\int \sqrt{5-x^2} d x \\
& =-x \sqrt{5-x^2}+\int \frac{5-x^2}{\sqrt{5-x^2}} d x \\
& =-x \sqrt{5-x^2}+5 \int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{5-x^2}}-I \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left[5 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}}\right)-x \sqrt{5-x^2}\right]+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you that is clear.